# how to allow editing of the sender address in roundcube

Tags: debian-squeeze, roundcube, webmail

I have installed roundcube webmail on my debian squeeze box. I want to know can I allow editing of the sender address in roundcube ? If yes, then how ? I searched so many blogs, posts but I didn't find any related help from their. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Rahul. I think that we can omit the "Debian squeeze" tag since Roundcube is a PHP software and Debian has not any customization related to Roundcube identities, so this question is really independent to Debian squeeze. Do you agree to de-tag it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit the actual email field of the Identity Settings instead of choosing available ones from a drop-down-menu, you have to set this in your roundcube/config/config.inc.php:

```
$config['identities_level'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is `Sender Identities` in RoundCibe settings.

When you've logged into RoundCube, go to your settings and you should see on option for `Sender Identities`. With this you can configure multiple, or change the default, sender so you can send from multiple accounts or email addresses on the one login.

I've also found a link on the RoundCube website which should explain it further. https://docs.roundcube.net/doc/help/1.1/en_US/settings/identities.html